Does Windows Spotlight have a shortcut to save the desktop to the "Pictures" folder?
My Win11 desktop is Windows Focus. In the middle of this month, I found two desktop background files that I had used before in the "Pictures" folder. The picture names and sizes are consistent with the cache in the system folder.
According to the time when the pictures were saved, I was browsing the web normally without using other third-party software. If I have to say there was any special operation, it might be that my cat passed by the keyboard and triggered a shortcut key. This question has also been asked in the Microsoft community, but no one knows it yet.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

edit your question to include the link to the question in Microsoft community, and links to any other relevant research you have already done
